# Complex result or solution of an improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

The indefinite integral

$\displaystyle \int \frac{\ln (x)}{x^2-2 x+1} \, dx$

has the solution

$\ln (1-x)+\frac{x \ln (x)}{1-x} +C$

Taking the limit as $x$ approaches infinity

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty } \, \left(\ln (1-x)+\frac{x \ln (x)}{1-x}\right)= i \pi$

Also

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0 } \, \left(\ln (1-x)+\frac{x \ln (x)}{1-x}\right)= 0$

This means that

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty } \frac{\ln (x)}{x^2-2 x+1} \, dx = i \pi$

However there is the argument that the integration is over the real plane, the limit does not exist as $x$ approaches zero, and a complex solution was found, so there might be a contradiction.

How can this be explained or resolved?

Comment: $x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2$, so the integrand has a singularity at $x=1$.

Comment: In any case, a $\displaystyle\ln$-branch cut must be introduced BEFORE you talk about ANY limit.

Comment: Could we explain the complex solution found ($i \pi$) by saying that the integration was extended to the complex plane?

Answer (score 7):

Since$$\ln (1-x)+\frac{x \ln (x)}{1-x}$$is defined only when $x\in(0,1)$, it is not true that$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln (1-x)+\frac{x \ln (x)}{1-x}=i\pi.$$

Comment: It's not remotely true that $x\in (0,1)$.. Any branch of the logarithm with no cut along the real axis suffices...

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen If you are working in the original context of the question, it is, since it was specified that they were looking at the integral without complex analysis to start. If you take $x\leq 0$, the second summand has a logarithm of a negative number and if you take $x\geq 0$, the first summand is the logarithm of a negative number, both of which violate that constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Complex analysis methods to *compute* integrals don't prove that the integral exists, they just give you a candidate answer. You can blindly apply many rules to get nonsensical answers. An example in a similar vein: an antiderivative of $x^{-2}$ by power rule is $-x^{-1}$ and hence $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{x^2} = -2.$$ But observe $1/x^2 > 0$, so surely we should also have $-2>0$?

Comment: "*Complex analysis methods to compute integrals don't prove that the integral exists [...]*. Yes they do, when applied correctly.

Comment: I'm not aware of this, @AccidentalFourierTransform can you provide an example for me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#Examples

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform can you explain how they prove that the integral exists? Eg for sinc x you would cut out a symmetric region around 0 which is akin to a Cauchy principal value, right?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform notably in the definition of an improper Riemann integral you need to be able to jointly take the endpoints to $\pm \infty$, which is not implied by the existence of the limit as $a\to\infty$ of the integral over $[-a-,a]$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor it's true that the PV may be defined when the improper Riemann integral is not (but must agree when it does!) Of course, I would argue that at the end of the day the Riemann Integral isn't what one should be focusing on, but instead the PV and its generalizations, which have common use in physics and math alike